# Python script takes username as empty

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I'm having a problem with my python script code.Python plays the role as a server.
This is my login form:

```
<form id="registration" action=>
            <label id = "kjo" for="button">EMAIL:</label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" id="username" placeholder="USERNAME"><br><br>
            <label for="button">PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="password" name="PASS" id="userpwd" placeholder="PASSWORD"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" id="butt">
            <br><br>
            <a href="register.html">Premiere Connexion? </a>
        </form>
```

and this is my python script:

```
print('Cache-Control: no-cache')
print('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8')
print('')


data_file = open('../data/user.dat','rb')
data = pickle.loads(data_file.read())
data_file.close()


form_data = dict()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
for name in form.keys():
    if name.lower() == 'userpwd':
        form_data[name] = hashlib.sha512(form.getfirst(name).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    else:
        form_data[name] = form.getfirst(name)


if not 'username' in form_data:
    print('The username should not be empty')
elif not 'userpwd' in form_data:
    print('Le mot de pass ne doit pas Ãªtre vide.')
elif form_data['username'] == data['username'] and form_data['userpwd'] == data['userpwd']:
    print("Bonjour %s %s !" % (data['firstname'], data['lastname']))
else:
    print('Le nom d\'utilisateur et le mot de pass sont invalides.')
```

When I log in (after being registered) the message that appears : **The username should not be empty.** I dont understand why it takes the username that I type as empty? Can anyone explain to me please?

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML form the name for the username field is 'uname' so you should be checking for that.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
for name in form.keys():
    if name.lower() == 'userpwd':
        form_data[name] = 
hashlib.sha512(form.getfirst(name).encode('utf- 
8')).hexdigest()
     else:
         form_data[name] = form.getfirst(name)

if not 'uname' in form_data:
     print('The username should not be empty')
 elif not 'userpwd' in form_data:
     print('Le mot de pass ne doit pas Ãªtre vide.')
 elif form_data['uname'] == data['username'] and 
 form_data['userpwd'] == data['userpwd']:
     print("Bonjour %s %s !" % (data['firstname'], 
 data['lastname']))
 else:
      print('Le nom d\'utilisateur et le mot de pass sont invalides.')
```